# Does PathCchCombine is a secure version of PathCombine

Tags: c++, window, fortify

After Fortify scan, it complain about `PathCombine` function

```
TCHAR buff[_MAX_MAX_PATH];
PathCombine(buff, s1, strTemp);
```

So I'm thinking to use `PathCchCombine` instead. because it uses "The size of the destination buffer" as an argument. Can I say that is secure enough. Or is there any better way than this.

Answer (score 1):

It does depend on what you want to achieve exactly.

As a basic principle for combining two path fragments PathCChCombine is safer in some important ways.

***For clarity:***

1. It does NOT prevent the output buffer from overflowing.
2. It does NOT allow you to have a destination buffer longer than MAX_PATH
3. IT DOES give you better feedback in the form of a HRESULT where you can construct better flow handling rather than getting a nasty memory exception.
4. It DOES accept paths with "\", "\?\" and "\?\UNC\" prefixes which PathCombine does NOT.

**Is there a better way:**

Well this is where it depends on your assumptions. But assuming by your question that you want to handle returned paths (output buffer) longer than MAX_PATH then you should look at

[PathCChCombineEx:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707077(v=vs.85).aspx)

This function allows you to set a destination buffer longer than MAX_PATH. To do so you need to set the final parameter (dwFlags) with **PATHCCH_ALLOW_LONG_PATHS**(0x00000001).

> NOTE: When the PATHCCH_ALLOW_LONG_PATHS flag is set the output buffer
>   must be more than MAX_PATH

[PathAllocCombine:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707077(v=vs.85).aspx)

This function differs from PathCchCombine and PathCchCombineEx in that
the output buffer is created on the heap. This means you don't need to
declare the size of the returned string and reduces stack use.

Comment: PathCChCombineEx:

Minimum supported client Windows 8 [desktop apps | UWP apps]
Minimum supported server Windows Server 2012 [desktop apps | UWP apps]

Comment: PathAllocCombine:
Minimum supported client Windows 8 [desktop apps | UWP apps]
Minimum supported server Windows Server 2012 [desktop apps | UWP apps]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, can be simpler just to set the current directory to the first path.
(SetCurrentDirectory function). For example when you just want to check if some file in the path exists and it is in a relative path form.